# @SpringApplicationConfiguration without @IntegrationTest

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

right now, I start my Spring Boot Integration tests with

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTest
@ActiveProfiles("it")
public class AbstractIntegrationTest {
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Inject
    private EmbeddedWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Inject
    private RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter;

    @Before
    public void mockMvcSetUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .addFilter(requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter)
            .build();
    }
}
```

However, this always starts a fully leaded servlet container that listens on a port because my `Application.class` is annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Since I use `MockMvc` instead of `RestTemplate`s (I like the fluent interface of `MockMvc` way more than `RestTemplate`s), I figure it should be possible to not start a fully loaded container.

Could anyone please educate me if this is possible and if so, how?

Thanks,
Robin

Comment: Have you tried it? Have you read the document of `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`?